# org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI

Tags: java, css, spring, spring-mvc

I referred to many posts but still I was unable to solve this problem.

[image]

I have tried putting this css folder in WEB-INF and within views folder as well.
But still the styles are not reflected in the view page.

Here is my servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ctc.event.control" />

</beans:beans>
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

This is my style sheet ExpenseDetailsStyles.css

```
#ItemDiv1_Table1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#ItemDiv1Table2 {
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    font-size:30px;
}
```

and my view page.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="TagIncludes.jsp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Expense Details</title>
<link href='<c:url value="/resources/css/ExpenseDetailsStyles.css" />' rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type='text/javascript' src="../js/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form name="ExpenseDetails" method="Post"
        action="ExpenseDetailsForm.html">
        <div id="ItemDiv1">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table id="ItemDiv1_Table1">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Item</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="Item1" id="Item1" required /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Expense in Rs</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="ItemValue1" id="ItemValue1" ></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table id="ItemDiv1_Table2">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Edit</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the controller

```
@Controller
public class ExpenseFormController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ExpenseDetailsForm.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String openForm() {
        return "ExpenseDetailsForm";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/ExpenseDetailsForm.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitForm() {
        return null;

    }
}
```

stacktrace is not an error but a warning.

> WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Calculator/`<c:url value="css/ExpenseDetailsStyles.css" />`] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

I think there is some problem with my uri in the view page and I tried changing it in many different ways.
Can anyone please help me correct the uri and reflect the styles on the view page?
Please comment if any other information pertaining this, is needed.

Comment: you may want to add a bit more information on the problem you are having? Can you attach your annotated controller as well?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @KyelJmD The uri in the view page could be wrong. I don't know what would be wrong. Struck here for the last 1 day.

Comment: Post your controller code, and the stacktrace.

Comment: `<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`  I think you don't need this now that you added `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />` in the xml.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the following

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

mapping some resources to the Spring servlet but you don't have any controller handler methods to serve them up. You should remove the above `servlet-mapping`s and put your `css` resources in `/resources/css` and `js` resources in `/resources/js`. Spring will know to get them automatically from there because of the `<mvc:resources>` element.

Make sure to also change the hard-coded location of your scripts and css in html files.

Also, on this line

```
<link href='<c:url value="/resources/css/ExpenseDetailsStyles.css" />' ... />
```

use double quotes `"`. You might also want to refactor to this

The `<c:url>` tag will put the value into the variable `myvar` which will then be available in your `<link>` tag.

Also you need this line at the top of your jsp to tell it you need jstl tags:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: I have removed the `servlet-mapping` for `css` and `js`. I have this, '<c:url value="css/ExpenseDetailsStyles.css" />' in the html. Is this correct?

Comment: By the way, the `resources` we are talking about is the one in `src/main/webapp` and not the one `src/main/`, am I right?

Comment: I believe it should be `<c:url value="/resources/css/Expens...`> and in `src/main/webapp`

Comment: It is still not working, even after using `src/main/webapp` and `c:url value="/resources/css/Expens...`. I think there is something else missing in the `resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" /`

Comment: @Freakyuser update your question with the modified web.xml, servlet-context.xml, and jsp

Comment: This looks like the correct setup to me. Try cleaning your project, rebuilding, and running it again. And show us what new error occurs if it does.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25162/discussion-between-freakyuser-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Answer (score 0):

In you context file, add the following:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
```

This adds a static path, /resources/.  Simply place your content there.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I already have it in my servlet-context.xml. I have posted it above.